# Interpretation of specific Hamiltonian operator

Tags: mathematics, terminology-and-notation, projection-operator

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05820 the authors introduce several Hamiltonians. For example they define
$$
H_G = A^\dagger \left( \mathbb{I} - \vert b \rangle \langle b \vert \right) A
$$
in equation (4), where $A$ is a complex-weighted sum of unitary matrices and $\vert b \rangle$ a quantum state prepared with the unitary $U$ (that will appear later in the question): $U\vert 0 \rangle = \vert b \rangle$.

This Hamiltonian is depicted as the "global" Hamiltonian and is defined such as its expectation value when the system is in the state $\vert x \rangle$ is
$$
\langle x \vert H \vert x \rangle = \langle x \vert \left[ A^\dagger \left( \mathbb{I} - \vert b \rangle \langle b \vert \right) A \right]\vert x \rangle = \langle \psi \vert \left( \mathbb{I} - \vert b \rangle \langle b \vert \right) \vert \psi \rangle
$$
where $\vert \psi \rangle = A \vert x \rangle$.

I may be wrong, but I think this expectation value can be interpreted as the "part" of $\vert \psi \rangle$ that is in the subspace orthogonal to $\vert b \rangle$.

The authors also define a "local" Hamiltonian:
$$
H_L = A^\dagger U \left( \mathbb{I} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \vert 0_j \rangle \langle 0_j \vert \otimes \mathbb{I}_{\bar{j}} \right) U^\dagger A
$$
where $U$ is a unitary matrix "preparing" $\vert b \rangle$ and $\mathbb{I}_\bar{j}$ is the identity operation on all qubits except the $j$-th one.

My question is: is there a interpretation of the formula for $H_L$ as I wrote above for $H_G$? I particularly need help for the interpretation of the sum, I would tend to say it is a projection on all the states that have their $j$-th qubit in the $\vert 0 \rangle$ state, but I am not sure.

EDIT: after more research, [this notebook](https://pennylane.ai/qml/app/tutorial_vqls.html) gave me a re-formulation of one of the terms:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \vert 0_j \rangle \langle 0_j \vert \otimes \mathbb{I}_\bar{j} = P = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathbb{I} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Z_j \right)
$$
where $Z_j$ is the $\sigma_z$ Pauli matrix applied to the $j$-th qubit, qubit indexes starting with $0$.

NOTE: the question is open, i.e. a possible answer could be "I am pretty sure there is no easy interpretation of that thing".

Comment: As DaftWullie pointed out in the comments to my deleted answer, $I - P$ isn't a projection operator indeed. However, I do believe that there should be a simple interpretation of that term in terms of a [restricted/local Hamiltonians](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/qhc_survey_final_ebook.pdf) (it's a big deal in perturbation theory). For instance. $I - P$ acts non-trivially only on the subspace in which the $j$-th qubit is $|0\rangle$. Nonetheless, it is evident why when $|\psi\rangle \propto |b\rangle$ the energy (cost) function vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, let's look at $$\mathbb I - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \vert 0_j \rangle \langle 0_j \vert \otimes \mathbb{I}_\bar{j} =\mathbb I -  P.$$

We can rewrite $$\mathbb I = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb I = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\left|0_j\rangle\langle 0_j\right| + \left|1_j\rangle\langle 1_j\right|\right)\otimes \mathbb I_\bar j$$ to get $$\mathbb I - P = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left|1_j\rangle\langle 1_j\right|\otimes \mathbb I_{\bar j}.$$

This is a normalised sum of projectors $$\mathbb I - P =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb P_{1,j}$$ where $\mathbb P_{1, j}$ projects the $j^{\text{th}}$ qubit into state $\left|1\right>$. That is, $\mathbb I - P$ gives the proportion of qubits in state $\left|1\right>$, or more accurately, the expectation value of $\mathbb I-P$ with respect to some state gives the expected proportion of qubits to return $'1'$ when that state is measured. Equivalently, the expectation value of $P$ is the expected proportion of qubits to return $'0'$ when measured.

As $U\left|0\right> = \left|b\right>$, $U\left(\mathbb I - P\right)U^\dagger$ does with $\left|b\right>$ what $\mathbb I - P$ does with $\left|0\right>$.

Of course, the difficulty now is that $\left|b\right>$ can presumably be an entangled state, so explaining this in terms of "expectation value of the proportion of qubits returning $'1'$ upon measurement" isn't quite so straightforward.

However, **asking the question 'are you measuring the state $\left|b\right>$?', $\left<x|H_L|x\right>$ is the expectation value of the proportion of qubits that would return 'no'.**

An alternative way of thinking about it that might make more sense in this context is by realising that if $A\left|x\right> = \left|b\right> = U\left|0\right>$, $U^\dagger A\left|x\right> = \left|0\right>$ and so we arrive back at **the expectation value of the proportion of qubits returning $'1'$ upon measurement of $U^\dagger A\left|x\right>$.**

Comment: Very nice answer! It took me a little bit of time to understand it, but it seems like it solves my problem. The conclusions are coherent with the context and fit nicely, I am happy with this! Thanks a lot!